# how to make an imageview fits the screen in fragment layout / constraint or frame layout /

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make an imageView fits the constraintlayout of a fragment 
when I run the code I get part of the image fitting the screen not the full image 
this is the xml of my fragment

today_fragment.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/prague"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </ImageView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is

TodayFragment.kt

```
class TodayFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var info :CardviewWeatherInfo
    lateinit var prague :ImageView
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.today_fragment, container , false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }


}
```

this is the original image:

[image: this is the original image]

and this is what I get when I run the code

[image]

Comment: Please post the preview of image and what you want.

Comment: @Ashish
I have added the image and the result 
I want the original image to be shown

Answer (score 0):

You can try with two android attributes for an ImageView:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

The option fitCenter tells the image to always center itself to the size of its layout container.
The option adjustViewBounds tells the image to fit in its layout.